# Simulating a moving location with React Native geolocation

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app with geolocation features, but i'm running into trouble simulating moving gps locations.

For example, running the freshly cloned React Native geolocation example inside the `Examples/UIExplorer` folder (setting the simulator location to "Freeway Drive"), the coordinates never get updated. There are no warnings or error messages in the console.

I've also ensured that UIExplorer/Info.plist has    `<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>` set.

Anyone know what could be going wrong, or has anyone managed to get geolocation working with React Native?